# Using URL variables in 'show' view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip

I'm working on a Ruby on Rails project that uses Paperclip for file uploads, S3 for storage, and does some back-end image conversion using [Blitline](http://blitline.com).  The result of the conversion gives the original and a file called `upload.png` in my S3 bucket alongside the original.

So, after conversion I've got two files something along the lines of:
`myaws.amazonaws.com/mybucket/model_id/original.pdf` and
`myaws.amazonaws.com/mybucket/model_id/upload.png`

Ideally, I would like to keep the original at hand in my bucket case my user needs to download it again, or if we need to do another conversion for some reason.

Is there a method similar to `<% = image_tag @attachment.url %>` that will specify the file 'upload.png'?

**Edit (More info:)**

I did attempt `<% = image_tag @attachment.url, :format => :png %>` though it does not work. Seems as if rails is still trying to pull it up as a PDF

Answer (score 0):

Have you specified a `style` for your attachment? If you have one, let's say `xyz` then you can get the url `<% = image_tag @attachment.url(:xyz) %>`

Comment: Good thought - I had one when I was using ImageMagick for conversion, but deleted it when moving to Blitline.  I added `:styles => { image: [ :png] }` to my model and `<%= image_tag @template.attachment.url(:image)%>` to my view...  Still get a broken link `foo.pdf`

Comment: Correction - now I'm getting a broken image link to `<img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/mybucket/images/sub_dir/images/272/original_filename.png" alt="Original_filename" />` - but as I mentioned above I need to access `upload.png`explicitly